# How to add a Sized supertrait to a Rust trait?

Tags: rust, traits

At [this issue page for Rust](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/33242), it gives the following example code for `core::num::bignum::FullOps`:

```
pub trait FullOps {
    ...
    fn full_mul(self, other: Self, carry: Self) -> (Self /*carry*/, Self);
    ...
}
```

Then it says that:

> Here the function `full_mul` returns a `(Self, Self)` tuple, which is only
>   well-formed when the `Self`-type is `Sized` - for that and other reasons,
>   the trait only makes sense when `Self` is `Sized`. The solution in this
>   case and most others is to add the missing `Sized` supertrait.

How does one add the missing `Sized` supertrait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple: change the first line to:

```
pub trait FullOps : Sized {
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=cb3e897258b6c40829a1adb17c95b19d&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Answer (score 4):

A "super trait" is just a bound, really.

You can place a bound either at trait level or method level. Here, you are advised to place it at trait level:

```
pub trait FullOps: Sized {
    fn full_mul(self, other: Self, carry: Self) -> (Self, Self);
}
```

The other solution would be to place it at method level:

```
pub trait FullOps {
    fn full_mul(self, other: Self, carry: Self) -> (Self, Self)
        where Self: Sized;
}
```